# How do i get text into a string variable from a selected option in dropdown using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
String city;
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("city"))); //Selects the dropdown menu 
dropdown.selectByValue(cityName); //selects Ajax as the city from the Dropdown menu
city = dropdown.selectByValue(cityName);
```

This is what i am using. But it does not work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the currently selected text from the dropdown, you can use 'getFirstSelectedOption' method, as shown below:

```
String city;
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("city")));     //Selects the dropdown menu 
dropdown.selectByValue(cityName); //selects Ajax as the city from the Dropdown menu
city = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
```

Please let me know, if I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Great. You are welcome. Could you please accept my answer and mark it as useful, if it worked as per your expectations :-).